# Plotly multiple Y values for the same X do not project the desired value

Tags: python, charts, plotly

I'm analyzing some data in a csv file (electricity usage over time)

The data can include multiple Y values for the same X DATE, something like :

```
TYPE,DATE,START TIME,END TIME,USAGE,UNITS,COST,NOTES
Electric usage,2021-04-08,00:00,00:59,0.93,kWh,$0.27,
Electric usage,2021-04-08,01:00,01:59,0.42,kWh,$0.12,
Electric usage,2021-04-08,02:00,02:59,0.49,kWh,$0.14,
Electric usage,2021-04-08,03:00,03:59,0.49,kWh,$0.14,
```

What I'm noticing in my script below is the values are not aggregated into a single value, at least not correctly.  Is there any way to do this ?

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
fig = px.line(df, x="DATE", y="USAGE")

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the data you provided, it's not obvious to the system that the values should be summed, you need to provide a summed dataframe first to have the data aggregate.

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
tmp = df.groupby("DATE")['USAGE'].sum().reset_index()
fig = px.line(tmp, x="DATE", y="USAGE")

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `WolVes` mention of needing to sum the values in a column you also need to have at least two points to make a line. And if you `groupby` on the `"DATE"` column you end up with a single row result for the data you shared.

So what I would recommend is to also enable point markers on the line, so that in case there is only row result you will still see a point show up on the graph:

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv").groupby("DATE")["USAGE"].sum().reset_index()
fig = px.line(df, x="DATE", y="USAGE")
fig.update_traces(mode="markers+lines")

fig.show()
```

One row result:

[image: one row result]

Two row result:

[image: two row result]